# Convert a dataframe's specific time format to another format in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm not able to convert the time values of the dataframe below to the "00:00:00" format. My goal is to be able to sum the values, but in the current string format it is not possible.

[image: dataframe]

Comment: Please consider adding a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of how you got to your dataframe, instead of the screenshot which doesn't tell us much about the structure of your dataframe.

Comment: @DocZerø The dataframe is just an Excel xlsx file. I just imported the file with pandas and printed the result on the screen.

Comment: could you edit your question to include the result of `df.head(5).to_dict()`?

Comment: Those look more like durations, so you might want to look into `timedelta`